# Concatenate in classic asp/vbscript SQL string

Tags: sql, join, concatenation

I'd like to select columns and join tables where the join condition concatenates the selected columns in additions to dots. For e.g.

```
SELECT TBL1.ID,
TBL1.COUNTRY As A,
TBL1.STATE As B,
TBL1.CODE As C
FROM TBL1, TBL2
WHERE TBL2.ID = A+'.'+B+'.'+C
```

The data is so that `TBL2.ID` looks like '**US.NY.61**' where **US** is `TBL1.COUNTRY`, **NY** is `TBL1.STATE`, etc.

UPDATE: SQl fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/26b6b/4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about trying something like this

```
SELECT TBL1.ID,
TBL1.COUNTRY As A,
TBL1.STATE As B,
TBL1.CODE As C
FROM TBL1 
  INNER JOIN TBL2 ON CAST(TBL1.COUNTRY AS varchar(20)) + '.' + CAST(TBL1.STATE AS varchar(20)) + '.' + CAST(TBL1.CODE AS varchar(20)) = CAST(TBL2.ID AS varchar(20))
```

Added code to cast the 4 fields as varchar before combining and comparing them.

Comment: i seem to have problems with data types, see sql fiddle

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T.name,T2.nam FROM
T INNER JOIN T2
ON T.id = (T2.one + '.' + CAST(T2.two as varchar(50)) + '.' + CAST( T2.thr as varchar(50) ))
```